# Can I use SNES controller parts for my raspberry pi?

Tags: gamepad

I am planning on making a handheld console for a school project. I am new to raspberry pi and plan on using the raspberry pi 3 model b. Can I use the buttons and dpad out of a SNES controller?

Comment: Like this? https://blog.petrockblock.com/2012/07/03/snesdev-rpi-a-snes-adapter-for-the-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

You want to reuse the controller? You can use a usb snes controller. If not want to use a usb controller, you can wire the snes controller to the gpio, there is [how to here](https://blog.petrockblock.com/2012/07/19/connecting-snes-sockets-to-the-raspberry-pi-an-assembly-guide/).